# Custom round style for radiogroup

Tags: android, xml, radio-button, material-design

I'm trying to make a custom style for a radiogroup buttons (or toggeable buttons) but i don't know if it's achievable.

Current style of my buttons:

[image: screenshot current style]

And i would like to achieve something like this

Desirable style:

[image: screenshot desirable style]

A plus would be to have an animation where the selected color "slide" between the buttons. I'm really novice when it comes to xml design and animation.
Any directions or suggestion on where i can learn something like this is good !

Thanks for your help.

Tom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create given xml files in drawable folder
gray_background.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#B9AFAF"/>
        <corners android:radius="30dp" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/black" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

yellow_background.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/orng"/>
        <corners android:radius="30dp" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/black"
            />
    </shape>
</item>
```

gray_round.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#B9AFAF"/>
        <corners android:radius="30dp" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#B9AFAF"
            />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Create activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/a_gray_background"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="A Voir"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/a_yellow_background"/>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:text="A Voir"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_30dp" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Now Create MainActivity.java Class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
RadioGroup radioGroup;
RadioButton rd1,rd2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    radioGroup=findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    rd1=findViewById(R.id.button1);
    rd2=findViewById(R.id.button2);

    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
        {
            if (checkedId == R.id.button1)
            {
               rd1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow_background);
              rd2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gray_round);

            }

          else   if (checkedId == R.id.button2)
            {
                rd1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gray_round);
                rd2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow_background);
            }
        }
    });
}}
```

Hope it will be helpful to you.

Thanks.

Comment: What a simple solution, i love it ! Tweak it a bit to have less height on the unselected item and it's perfect. Thx you very much.